# Python, импорт собственных модулей

Tags: python-3.x

Я недавно начал пользоваться Python3 и пытаюсь написать программу на Pygame. Код становится все более большим и хотелось бы разделить его на части, например, каждый класс в отдельный файл. Но у меня это не получается.
Я пробовал экспериментировать и создал в этой же папке два тестовых файла, в одном был класс с функцией вывода, а во второй файл я импортировал первый файл и вызвал функцию и все получилось. Я уже пытался использовать sys.path, но ничего не вышло, наверное, я не правильно его использовал.
При запуске кода вылезает эта ошибка: AttributeError: module 'GameObjectFile' has no attribute 'GameObject'
Вот мой код, не вдавайтесь особо в подробности:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import GameObjectFile
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
resolution = bg.get_rect()
resolution = resolution[2], resolution[3]
win = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
surf = pygame.Surface(resolution)
def window():
    global bg
    global resolution
    global win
    global surf
    surf.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(surf, (0, 0))
runGame = True
while runGame:
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runGame = False
    Player = GameObjectFile.GameObject(200, 500, 30, 30)
    window()
    pygame.display.update()
```

И вот файл, который я хочу импортировать:

```
import pygame
from pygame.rect import Rect
class GameObject:
   def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.Object = Rect(self.x, self.y, w, h)
    def set(self, speed, jumpStrength):
        self.speed = speed
        self.jumpStr = jumpStrength
    def Draw(self):
        return pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), self.Object, 0)
```

Comment: В показанном вами коде нет такой ошибки, `GameObjectFile.GameObject` отлично импортируется и используется (если поправить опечатку с отступом)

Comment: ide какая? GameObjectFile лежит в той же папке?

Comment: Запустил у тебя, поправив отступ и создав картинку bg.png — падает на строчке `self.x = x`, потому что переменной `x` у вас нет. Но ошибок с импортом никаких нет

Comment: лучше сделать from GameObjectFile import GameObject, а потом обращаться к его методам так: Player = GameObject(200, 500, 30, 30)

Comment: Где эта опечатка с отступом? Я ее не вижу. Сейчас скопировал оба кода и запускаю - выдает все ту же ошибку. Файлы в одной папке находятся. @andreymal

Comment: Все, я нашел отступ

Comment: Боже, ошибка была только в этом отступе, что ли, спасибо вам <3

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в отступе перед первой функцией в классе.